# react-admin missing in the HTTP Response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring, cors, react-admin

I'm trying to create a admin panel using [`react-admin`](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin).

Here is what I have done :

```
class AdminPanel extends React.Component{

    render() {
        return(
          <div>
              <Admin dataProvider={restProvider('http://localhost:8080')}>
                  <Resource name="u/all" list={PostList}/>
              </Admin>
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And in another js file, I have defined `PostList`.

In my server I am debugging if `/u/all` is getting any hit or not. It's getting.

But react.js giving me error, saying : **Error: The Content-Range header is missing in the HTTP Response. The simple REST data provider expects responses for lists of resources to contain this header with the total number of results to build the pagination. If you are using CORS, did you declare Content-Range in the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header?**

How can I solve this ?

PostList.js:

```
export const PostList = (props) => (

    <List {...props}>
        <Datagrid>
            <TextField source="userID" />
            <TextField source="username" />
            <DateField source="firstName" />
            <TextField source="middleName" />
            <TextField source="lastName" />
            <TextField source="profileImageURL" />
            <TextField source="joiningTime" />
            <EditButton basePath="/posts" />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

My Server side CORS:

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry
                        .addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000","http://localhost:3001")
                        .exposedHeaders("Content-Range");
            }
        };
    }
```

[image]

Still getting error, after adding exposed header:

[image]

Comment: Add `.exposedHeaders("Content-Range")`. See https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/CorsRegistration.html#exposedHeaders-java.lang.String...-

Comment: @sideshowbarker , tried that too, still getting error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is written [in the react-admin documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#usage):

> The simple REST client expects the API to include a Content-Range header in the response to getList calls. The value must be the total number of resources in the collection. This allows react-admin to know how many pages of resources there are in total, and build the pagination controls.
>
> ```
> Content-Range: posts 0-24/319
> ```
>
> If your API is on another domain as the JS code, you’ll need to whitelist this header with an Access-Control-Expose-Headers CORS header.
>
> ```
> Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Range
> ```

Comment: I have added `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` in CORS, still it gets error.. i have updated the question

Comment: In addition to exposing the header in CORS, your API route must also include the header in the response...

Comment: I tried, but I couldn't do so, even some que here doesn't have any answer or any accepted answer...

Comment: I have added content-range, it still gets error : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59891595/react-admin-no-access-control-allow-origin